# Overlapping brackets / parentheses while matching multiple optional Regex groups

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a path-like pattern, though I seem to run into bracket-troubles when trying to repeat a group.

Some patterns I would like to match:

```
e.g1: /s0me/p@th/2/json

e.g2: /path
```

So far I have this:

```
(^\/[^/]*)(\/[^/]*)?
```

Which only matches up to:

```
/s0me/p@th
```

I'm trying to do the following to have the second group repeated, however regex seems to think I'm closing brackets earlier/later than I want, causing errors:

```
(^\/[^/]*)[(\/[^/]*)?]*
```

ERROR: Unmatched closing parenthesis

I'm using https://www.regextester.com for this.

Thanks

Comment: You have to turn the question mark into an asterix `*` to repeat it 0+ times `(^\/[^/\n]*)(\/[^/\n]*)*` The question mark makes it optional, 0 - 1 times.

Comment: @The fourth bird ah thanks for the tip, although it seems to now just match everything, even characters that are outside of the pattern `(\/[^/]*)`

Comment: Did you mean a match like https://regex101.com/r/I1M5Il/1 because if you repeat the last group, only the value of the last iteration would be captured in the 2nd group.

Comment: Nice thank you for that! The '+' is a big help. Can I ask why not use this: `(^\/[^/]+)((/[^/]+)*)` instead? What's the use of the colon and line-feed expressions?

Comment: You could also do that but the negated character class also matches a newline. I have added an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unmatched parenthesis and I think you have put the closing parenthesis inside the character class, which would then match it literally.

```
(^\/[^/]*)[(\/[^/]*)?]*
           ^       ^
```

If you would correct for it putting it outside of the character class you will get an optional capturing group followed by repeating 0+ times `]` at the end.

If you only repeat the second capturing group, only the result of the [last iteration](https://regex101.com/r/1yxWQU/1) would be in that group.

If you want the result of the rest that followed you have to use a capturing group surrounding a repeating pattern:

```
(^\/[^/\n]*)((?:/[^/\n]+)*)
```

- `(` Capturing group 1

  - `^\/[^/\n]*` Assert start of string, match `/` followed by a negated character class which would also match a newline
- `)` Close group
- `(` Capturing group 2

  - `(?:/[^/\n]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching `/` followed by a negated character class
- `)` Close group

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I1M5Il/1)

Comment: Your solution match "NUL" character or ":", both are forbiden in file name.

Comment: @JánStibila Thank you for your comment. In that case those can be added to the negated character class. Note that the OP also makes use of `[^/]`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed `[^/]`, but since path can contain `/` and OP didn't mention he want to match only portions of path or filename, you can do it easier, without nested groups. See my answer. Maybe OP want's to achieve something different than I thin, in that case, solution may lie in combining both our answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what is your goal. I write following answer with assumption that you want to match POSIX path name. Since in Linux/Unix file name can contain any characters except NUL, : and /, this can be really hard (or easy, depends on what your input may be) to achieve.

Easiest way is to match every line, that does not contain those characters (except / because this is used in path):

```
^[^\x00:]+$
```

If we get any match, that means string may be a file name (or full path).

Then we can add assumption, that there won't be new line character in path name, so we can update regex to:

```
^[^\x00\n:]+$
```

Sometimes we want only absolute path, so we match / at the beginning of the string:

```
^/[^\x00\n:]+$
```

You can also add requirement, that path leads at least 2 directories down from root:

```
^(/[^\x00\n:/]*){3,}$
```

We can add more restrictions of file names, but you get the point.

You may want to capture each path segment into a group, then you may have a problem, because we don't know how many groups there would be. It may, or may not be achievable with recursion, but not every regex engine supports it.

Comment: Thank you for the input.

Comment: I was actually trying to match json paths for the Java Jackson library, but because there are no in-built functions to do this, I had to resort to using regex